# Can't import statements outside modules in TypeScript despite changing package.json and tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I've been trying to learn how to unit-test with TypeScript using Mocha and Chai. I have some very simple code:

```
import { Calculator } from '../src/calculator';
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('calculator', function()
{
    it('should initialze with a calculated value of 0', function()
    {
        let calculator = new Calculator();
        expect(calculator.value).to.equal(0);
    });
});
```

Yet despite setting "type: module" in my package.json and "module: es2015" in my tsconfig.json, I keep getting the error about how I can't import from outside of a module.

Is there something I'm missing? I've done a bunch of searching, and the aforementioned fixes are the only ones I've found.

Comment: Tespy, are you using the include field in the tsconfig? if you do, are you including the test folder there?

Comment: @dave008 Which include field?

Comment: check here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html, for example:

Comment: {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2018"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2018",
    "outDir": "lib",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "tests/**/*"
  ]
}

Comment: @dave008 I've added that include field to my tsconfig.json, and I get an error that says "Unknown compiler option 'include'."

Comment: @dave008 Nevermind, I just implemented it wrong. After doing it right, the unit test ran properly. Thank you! ^_^